# Python update object from dictionary

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

Is there a built-in function/operator I could use to unpack values from a dictionary and assign it into instance variables?

This is what I intend to do:

```
c = MyClass()
c.foo = 123
c.bar = 123

# c.foo == 123 and c.bar == 123


d = {'bar': 456}
c.update(d)

# c.foo == 123 and c.bar == 456
```

Something akin to dictionary `update()` which load values from another dictionary but for plain object/class instance?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

there is also another way of doing it by looping through the items in d. this doesn't have the same assuption that they will get stored in `c.__dict__` which isn't always true.

```
d = {'bar': 456}
for key,value in d.items():
    setattr(c,key,value)
```

or you could write a `update` method as part of `MyClass` so that `c.update(d)` works like you expected it to.

```
def update(self,newdata):
    for key,value in newdata.items():
        setattr(self,key,value)
```

check out the help for setattr

> ```
> setattr(...)
>     setattr(object, name, value)
>     Set a named attribute on an object; setattr(x, 'y', v) is equivalent to
>     ''x.y = v''.
> ```

Comment: I already know about setattr... Can you explain more on why some items would not be in __dict__ ? I actually ended up still using this kind of loop+setattr because __dict__ somehow wasn't available.

Comment: sure, the main difference is between class attributes and instance attributes. Only the latter are in `__dict__`. so if you have

class Test:
   a = 1

t = Test()

the object `t` has an empty `__dict__` because a is a class attribute

t.b = 2

now it has a `__dict__` of `{'b':2}`

Comment: and where are class attributes stored? in `Test.__dict__` I suppose? (it would be ok)

Answer (score 35):

Have you tried

```
f.__dict__.update( b )
```

?

Comment: http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/ref/types.html or http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy.   The section titled "classes" is pretty explicit on precisely how this works.

Comment: This will silently misbehave when a class attribute isn't stored in the instance's `__dict__`. E.g., properties and class attributes. In general, Jehiah's answer is safer.

Comment: setattr is the most preferable way to go here. Using internal object.__dict__ is not recommended.

Comment: this misbehaved for me exactly as @Jon-Eric described

Answer (score 9):

Also, maybe it would be good style to have a wrapper around the dict's update method:

```
def update(self, b):
    self.__dict__.update(b)
```

PS: Sorry for not commenting at @[S.Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10661/s-lott) 's post but I don't have the rep yet.

Comment: Duplicate of S.Lott's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing:

```
def to_object(my_object, my_dict):
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        attr = getattr(my_object, key)
        if hasattr(attr, '__dict__'):
            to_object(attr, value)
        else:
            setattr(my_object, key, value)

obj = MyObject()
data = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
to_object(obj, data)
```